# Non-deterministic unit tests with Rx, Xamarin

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, system.reactive, non-deterministic

So I'm writing unit tests for one of my view models in Xamarin mobile app. The method I'm testing looks like this:

```
public async Task RefreshItems()
{
    var departamentsObservable = _dataService.GetDepartaments();

    departamentsObservable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(items =>
    {
        Departaments.ReplaceWithRange(items);
    });

    await departamentsObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

`_dataService.GetDepartaments();` method returns `IObservable<IEnumerable<Departament>>`.

I use `Observable` and `Subscribe` instead of simple method that returns `Task<IEnumerable<Departament>>` because in my case `Observable` will "return" twice (once with data from cache and other time with newly fetched data form web).

For testing I of course mock `_dataService.GetDepartaments();` method like that:

```
public IObservable<IEnumerable<Departament>> GetDepartaments()
{
    return Observable.Return(MockData.Departaments);
}
```

So method returns mock data immediately.

And my test for `RefreshItems` method looks like that:

```
[Fact]
public async Task RefreshItemsTest()
{
    await _viewModel.RefreshItems();

    Assert.Equal(MockData.Departaments, _viewModel.Departaments, 
                 new DepartamentComparer());
}
```

The problem is that this test randomly fails (1 in 10 times approximately). Basically The `Departaments` collection in view model that should be updated when `Observable` "returns" is empty.

I should add that I'm using xUnit 2.1.0 test framework and xUnit console runner in Xamarin Studio.

**EDIT:**
The Enigmativity's suggestion throws *Sequence contains no elements* exception only when running in test runner. Below is minimal woking example code to demonstrate the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class TestViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TestDepartament> Departaments { get; set; }

        private ITestDataService _dataService;

        public TestViewModel(ITestDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
            Departaments = new ObservableCollection<TestDepartament>();
        }

        public async Task RefreshItems()
        {
            var facultiesObservable = _dataService.GetDepartaments();

            await facultiesObservable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Do(items =>
            {
                Departaments.Clear();
                foreach(var item in items)
                    Departaments.Add(item);
            });
        }
    }

    public interface ITestDataService
    {
        IObservable<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>> GetDepartaments();
    }

    public class MockDataService : ITestDataService
    {
        public IObservable<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>> GetDepartaments()
        {
            return Observable.Return(TestMockData.Departaments);
        }
    }

    public static class TestMockData
    {
        public static List<TestDepartament> Departaments
        {
            get
            {
                var departaments = new List<TestDepartament>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    departaments.Add(new TestDepartament
                    {
                        Name = $"Departament {i}",
                        ImageUrl = $"departament_{i}_image_url",
                        ContentUrl = $"departament_{i}_content_url",
                    });
                }

                return departaments;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestDepartament
    {
        public string ContentUrl { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is xUnit test:

```
public class DepartamentsViewModelTests
{
    private readonly TestViewModel _viewModel;

    public DepartamentsViewModelTests()
    {
        var dataService = new MockDataService();
        _viewModel = new TestViewModel(dataService);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task RefreshItemsTest()
    {
        await _viewModel.RefreshItems();

        Assert.Equal(TestMockData.Departaments, _viewModel.Departaments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged and compared the results manually? Perhaps the `DepartmentComparer` is flawed?

Comment: @m-y Thanks for your response. Yes I have debugged my test and the length of Departaments collection in view model is indeed 0 when test fails.

Answer (score 2):

Is your intention to block some GUI while this Refresh takes place. By block I mean block user progress by showing a spinner or other non-deterministic progress bar? Or Do you want the user to be able to continue doing what they were doing, but be able to signal that there is some background process happening, and also signal when that process is done?

For the Former, I would think that the current signature you have is sensible i.e. you return a `Task`. However the implementation I think can be improved.

```
public async Task RefreshItems()
{
    var items = await _dataService.GetDepartaments()
        .Take(1)
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .ToTask();

    Departaments.ReplaceWithRange(items);
}
```

Note the `Take(1)`. If you try to convert from `IObservable<T>` to `Task<T>`/`Task`, you only get the last value, or yield when the sequence is complete. Without the `Take(1)` we could just wait forever.
However, I think you have a scenario that you are loading from a cache, so can get 0,1 or 2 OnNext calls. In this scenario, I don't know what waiting for the last value achieves? I also note the lack error handling.

I would probably in my own code do something like this FWIW

```
public void RefreshItems()
{
    Departments.Clear();
    _state = States.Processing();
    var items =  _dataService.GetDepartaments()
        .SubscribeOn(_schedulerProvider.Background)
        .ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Foreground)
        .Subscribe(
            item=> Departaments.Add(item),
            ex => _state = States.Faulted(ex),
            () => _state = States.Idle());
}
```

This allows

- the `_states` field/property to reflect what is currently going on (processing, idle or some error),
- items to be added to the `Departments` list as the arrive instead of in one big block,
- Doesn't mix `Task` and `IObservable<T>`
- Has a single place to dictate concurrency model. It appears that there is something that is switching threads in your program that isn't in your code, as you have an `ObserveOn` but no matching `SubscribeOn`.

**Edit**

Here is a style I would go about creating this viewmodel. I prefer not to mix Task and IObservable. I also favor using Schedulers over Synchronization contexts. I have added resource management so that the subscriptions don't overlap (if Refresh is called multiple times) and so that it can be cancelled when the ViewModel is finished with. Here it should be easy to test 0,1 or many values being yielded. It also allows testing for error scenarios (e.g. OnError via Timeouts, Network outages etc.).

I also just for fun added the Async State property so that external consumers can see that the ViewModel is currently processing something.

I do however overload the test to have many concerns. I probably wouldn't do this in practice, but I think it makes it easier to read for SO.

http://share.linqpad.net/67hmc2.linq

```
void Main()
{
    var schedulerProvider = new TestSchedulerProvider();

    var cachedData = Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(i => new TestDepartament
    {
        Name = $"Departament {i}",
        ImageUrl = $"departament_{i}_image_url",
        ContentUrl = $"departament_{i}_content_url",
    }).ToArray();

    var liveData = Enumerable.Range(10, 5).Select(i => new TestDepartament
    {
        Name = $"Departament {i}",
        ImageUrl = $"departament_{i}_image_url",
        ContentUrl = $"departament_{i}_content_url",
    }).ToArray();

    var data = schedulerProvider.Background.CreateColdObservable<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>>(100, cachedData),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>>(3000, liveData),
        ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>>(3000));

    var dataService = Substitute.For<ITestDataService>();
    dataService.GetDepartaments().Returns(data);

    var viewModel = new TestViewModel(dataService, schedulerProvider);

    Assert.Equal(AsyncState.Idle, viewModel.State);

    viewModel.RefreshItems();
    Assert.Equal(AsyncState.Processing, viewModel.State);

    schedulerProvider.Background.AdvanceTo(110);
    schedulerProvider.Foreground.Start();

    Assert.Equal(cachedData, viewModel.Departments);

    schedulerProvider.Background.Start();
    schedulerProvider.Foreground.Start();

    Assert.Equal(liveData, viewModel.Departments);
    Assert.Equal(AsyncState.Idle, viewModel.State);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ITestDataService _dataService;
    private readonly ISchedulerProvider _schedulerProvider;
    private readonly SerialDisposable _refreshSubscription = new SerialDisposable();
    private AsyncState _state = AsyncState.Idle;

    public ObservableCollection<TestDepartament> Departments { get;} = new ObservableCollection<UserQuery.TestDepartament>();
    public AsyncState State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(State));
        }
    }


    public TestViewModel(ITestDataService dataService, ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    public void RefreshItems()
    {
        Departments.Clear();
        State = AsyncState.Processing;
        _refreshSubscription.Disposable = _dataService.GetDepartaments()
            .SubscribeOn(_schedulerProvider.Background)
            .ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Foreground)
            .Subscribe(
                items =>
                {
                    Departments.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        Departments.Add(item);  
                    }
                },
                ex => State = AsyncState.Faulted(ex.Message),
                () => State = AsyncState.Idle);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _refreshSubscription.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface ITestDataService
{
    IObservable<IEnumerable<TestDepartament>> GetDepartaments();
}

public interface ISchedulerProvider
{
    IScheduler Foreground { get;}
    IScheduler Background { get;}
}
public class TestSchedulerProvider : ISchedulerProvider
{
    public TestSchedulerProvider()
    {
        Foreground = new TestScheduler();
        Background = new TestScheduler();
    }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.Foreground { get { return Foreground; } }
    IScheduler ISchedulerProvider.Background { get { return Background;} }
    public TestScheduler Foreground { get;}
    public TestScheduler Background { get;}
}
public sealed class AsyncState
{
    public static readonly AsyncState Idle = new AsyncState(false, null);
    public static readonly AsyncState Processing = new AsyncState(true, null);

    private AsyncState(bool isProcessing, string errorMessage)
    {
        IsProcessing = isProcessing;
        IsFaulted = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage);
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
    }

    public static AsyncState Faulted(string errorMessage)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return new AsyncState(false, errorMessage);
    }

    public bool IsProcessing { get; }
    public bool IsFaulted { get; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }
}

public class TestDepartament
{
    public string ContentUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Lee. I am using Akavache framework and its `GetAndFetchLatest` method. So the observable might "return" 0, 1 or 2 times. I show spinner to user while there are no data at all. When any data (local or fetched) arrives and populates `Departments` observable collection I remove the spinner. If data arrives second time (i.e first local then newly fetched), I silently update `Departaments` observable collection. In the whole process UI is not blocked once, so user can perform any action at any time. I'm still new to Rx and I will try out your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @ Lee - I tried out your code and it appears to be working. In your example you are `await`'ing the whole expression but that overload of `Subscribe` returns `IDisposable` so I think thats a typo. Am I right? If I am, this posses one problem - the `RefreshItems` method becomes impossible to test since there is nothing to `await`. Is my logic flawed in any way?

Comment: Correct. I had an incorrect `await` statement in there (you can't await a subscription). It is completely testable, as you are now using just Rx so can lean on the testing library.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "lean on the testing library"? How would I write a test that ensures that `RefreshItems` method actually populates `Departments` collection?

Comment: Updated the answer to have some code showing kinda what I mean.

Comment: It appears that indeed I can test everything by controlling the flow of time with the help of `TestScheduler`. I have still a lot to learn about Rx but your insights are very useful. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great answer HOWEVER how do you implement ISchedulerProvider for Xamarin Forms then?

Comment: I am not sure why it would be different. Might need to ask a xamarin expert

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating **two subscriptions** to the observable - sometimes `departamentsObservable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(...)` produces values **before** `await departamentsObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` completes and sometimes it **doesn't**.

Two subscriptions means two independent times that the source is run through. When the `await` completes quickly then your other subscription doesn't get called (or is called after your `Assert.Equal` is called), and hence the values are not added to the list.

Try this instead:

```
public async Task RefreshItems()
{
    var departamentsObservable = _dataService.GetDepartaments();

    await departamentsObservable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Do(items =>
    {
        Departaments.ReplaceWithRange(items);
    });
}
```

Now you only have one subscription that awaits the last value to be produced.

If you're only expecting one value, and the observable doesn't naturally end, then pop a `.Take(1)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I replaced my code with your suggestion, but I'm getting *Sequence contains no elements* exception.

Comment: @Andrius - where are you getting that error? Can you append the code to the bottom of your question?

Comment: I'm getting an exception on this line in my view model: `await departamentsObservable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Do(items =>` Let me know if you need some more code.

Comment: The exception appears to be thrown only when my code runs in test runner (I tried xUnit and NUnit runners). When i run my app on actual device everything works correctly regardless whether I use mocked `_dataService.GetDepartaments();` (which returns instantly as shown in question) or actual implementation. I feel really lost at this moment :)

Comment: @Andrius - It would be really great if you could append the code to the bottom of your question so that I could copy, paste, and run, to see the error myself.

Comment: sure, I removed all unnecessary dependencies and created minimal working example at the bottom of my question. You should be able to simply copy paste the code. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[@lee-campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393615/lee-campbell) 's answer is great but it is missing Xamarin Forms implementation of his `ISchedulerProvider`.

Here is what I use:

```
public sealed class SchedulerProvider : ISchedulerProvider
    {
        public IScheduler Foreground => new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);
        public IScheduler Background => TaskPoolScheduler.Default;
    }
```